# 100% width button group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap framework, how to set button group to 100% in the yellow panel?

See example:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/34406/

There should be no padding on the side.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color:pink; height: 500px">
      Content here
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:yellow; height: 500px">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Duplicate</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your button group is `inline-block` so you either need to change it to `block` or specify it to have `width:100%`

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle out. I have made new with what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/exuLo7f7/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>

.col-md-3{
    margin:0px!important;
    padding:0px!important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Justified Button Groups</h2>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color:yellow;">dsaaaaaaaasadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsad</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:black;">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apple</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Samsung</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sony</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap genuily adds 15px padding in col-* classes.

If you want to get rid of these paddings you need to force them out.
I added this class:

```
.no-padding {
  padding : 0 !important;
}
```

and it gave [these results](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/34412/).

Hope it helps.